# How to remove multi nested object in javascript using id

Tags: javascript, object

> **Declaration of id**

```
var id = 3;
```

> **I want to update this object**

```
var obj = {"comments" : {
                "commentedBy" : "test",
                "date" : "",
                "comment" : "Hello world",
                "subComments" : {
                    "commentedBy" : "jaril 2",
                    "date" : "",
                    "comment" : "Hello world inside dark",
                    "subComments" : {
                        "commentedBy" : "jaril 3",
                        "date" : "",
                        "comment" : "wow working great",
                        "subComments" : {
                            "commentedBy" : "jaril 4",
                            "date" : "",
                            "comment" : "wow working great",
                            "commentId" : 4
                        },
                        "commentId" : 3
                    },
                    "commentId" : 2
                },
                "commentId" : 1
            },
            "dueDate" : "",
            "createdDate" : "",
            "lastUpdated" : "",
            "checkList" : [],
            "position" : 2,
            "status" : "active"
        }
      }
```

> **Function is this**

```
function deleteCommentId(comments){
  if (comments.commentId == id)){
    delete comments;
    return comments;
  }
  if (comments.subComments) {
    deleteCommentId(comments.subComments);
  } 
  return comments;
}
```

> **Function Object is this**

```
if(id == 1){
    result[0].comments = {};
} else {
    deleteCommentId(obj.comments);
}
console.log("final object==>", obj);
```

> **I want output like this**

```
          {"comments" : {
                "commentedBy" : "test",
                "date" : "",
                "comment" : "Hello world",
                "subComments" : {
                    "commentedBy" : "jaril 2",
                    "date" : "",
                    "comment" : "Hello world inside dark",
                    "commentId" : 2
                },
                "commentId" : 1
            },
            "dueDate" : "",
            "createdDate" : "",
            "lastUpdated" : "",
            "checkList" : [],
            "position" : 2,
            "status" : "active"
        }
      }
```

> **Any help would be appreciated**
>
> Note: I want to remove nested subcomments object using id if I pass
>    id=3 then it should remove subcomment of 2, How can I remove subcomments of 2 if id = 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function below should do it.

(I removed the irrelevant parts or your object to make things a bit easier to read.)

```js
var obj = {
  "comments": {
    "subComments": {
      "subComments": {
        "subComments": {
          "commentId": 4
        },
        "commentId": 3
      },
      "commentId": 2
    },
    "commentId": 1
  }
};

function deleteCommentId(comments, id) {
  if (comments.subComments) {
    if (comments.subComments.commentId === id) {
      delete comments.subComments;
    } else {
      deleteCommentId(comments.subComments, id);
    }
  }
}

deleteCommentId(obj.comments, 3);
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var id = 3;
var obj = {"comments":{"commentedBy":"test","date":"","comment":"Hello world","subComments":{"commentedBy":"jaril 2","date":"","comment":"Hello world inside dark","subComments":{"commentedBy":"jaril 3","date":"","comment":"wow working great","subComments":{"commentedBy":"jaril 4","date":"","comment":"wow working great","commentId":4},"commentId":3},"commentId":2},"commentId":1},"dueDate":"","createdDate":"","lastUpdated":"","checkList":[],"position":2,"status":"active"}

function deleteCommentId(comments, id) {
  if (comments.subComments) {
    if (comments.subComments.commentId === id) {
      delete comments.subComments;
    } else {
      deleteCommentId(comments.subComments, id);
    }
  }
}

deleteCommentId(obj.comments, id);
console.log("final object==>",obj);


var expectedJSON = {"comments":{"commentedBy":"test","date":"","comment":"Hello world","subComments":{"commentedBy":"jaril 2","date":"","comment":"Hello world inside dark","commentId":2},"commentId":1},"dueDate":"","createdDate":"","lastUpdated":"","checkList":[],"position":2,"status":"active"}

console.log("Output match: ",JSON.stringify(obj) == JSON.stringify(expectedJSON));
```